# Democracy proposal not enacted

Tags: pallet, hash, call, democracy

First of all I am working on Polkadot-v0.9.29.
I am struggling to understand the right way to format a pallet call before submitting it as a proposal to the democracy pallet.
Let's the pallet call be the famous:

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1).ref_time())]
        pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, something: u32) -> DispatchResult {

            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            // Update storage.
            <Something<T>>::put(something);
            // Emit an event.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::SomethingStored { something, who });
            // Return a successful DispatchResultWithPostInfo
            Ok(())
        }
```

consider the following code:

I prepared a function that formats the call as follows:

```
pub fn create_proposal_hash_and_note(caller: T::AccountId,call:<T as Config>::Call) -> T::Hash {
        let origin = RawOrigin::Signed(caller);
        let call_wrap = Box::new(call);
        let proposal_hash = T::Hashing::hash_of(&call_wrap);
        let proposal_encoded: Vec<u8> = call_wrap.encode();
        match Dem::Pallet::<T>::note_preimage(origin.into(), proposal_encoded){
            Ok(_) => (),
            Err(x) if x == Error::<T>::DuplicatePreimage.into() => (),
            Err(x) => panic!("{:?}", x),
        }
        proposal_hash
    }
```

Then I create the formated call, submit the proposal and start a referendum:

```
let call = Call::<T>::do_something{
                something:32
            };
//Create and add the proposal
let prop_hash = Self::create_proposal_hash_and_note(virtual_account.clone(),rep_call.into());
Dem::Pallet::<T>::propose(origin_v.into(),prop_hash,deposit.into()).ok();
....
```

I Already checked through testing, that:

- the referendum is correctly started
- the proposal hash is registered
- after voting, the referendum completes normally
  only problem is the proposal is not enacted.
  I think it's because the proposal is not correctly formated, but I really don't know Where/why.
  If you want to see the full code:

[Asset_management_pallet](https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/tree/126-implement-asset-distributor-pallet-fungible-%2B-config-shares-that-get-minted/pallets/asset_management/src)

Help, please?

#### EDIT 1

Code sample of the test I'm using with the **Real pallet call**:

```
let b = match ref_infos{
            pallet_democracy::ReferendumInfo::Finished{approved,end:_} => approved,
            _=> false,
        } ;

        println!("\n\nReferendum status after vote is: {:?}\n present block is: {:?}\n\n",&ref_infos,System::block_number());
        println!("\n\nvote result is:{:?}",b);
        let prop0 = AssetManagement::proposals(0).unwrap().vote_result;
        println!("\n\nVote results:{:?}\n\n",prop0);

        //Proposal enactement should happen 2 blocks later 
        fast_forward_to(end_block_number
            .saturating_add(<Test as crate::Config>::Delay::get()));

//The code line below fails as the pallet call is not executed as it should         
assert_eq!(Roles::RepresentativeLog::<Test>::contains_key(FERDIE), true);
```

#### EDIT 2

In the event emitted after the vote, I get the following error message:

```
Invalid preimage
```

Comment: The pallet tests for you linked code work. Which test do you mean is failing?

Comment: Hello and thanks for looking into it!!you need to un-comment the last line in test.rs. this check should succeed if the call is correctly executed: `assert_eq!(Roles::RepresentativeLog::<Test>::contains_key(FERDIE), true); `

Answer (score 3):

So one of our team member solved this, but it also raised a bunch of other questions that I will add above the various code sections:

1. I don't understand why the solution won't work without the function below. Even the one who figured it out does not...

   `pub fn get_formatted_call(call: <T as Config>::Call) -> <T as Config>::Call {call}`
2. Creating the call, nothing special

   ```
        let proposal_call = Call::<T>::representative_approval {
            rep_account: representative.clone(),
            collection: collection_id,
            item: asset_id,
        };
   ```
3. I actually thought that democracy was taking care of the call_dispatch, but I guess we have to do it ourselves...also...why do we need `get_formatted_call`?? any Rust/Substrate wizard???

`let proposal = Box::new(Self::get_formatted_call(proposal_call.into()));`

```
let call = Call::<T>::execute_call_dispatch {
                account_id: virtual_account.clone(),
                proposal: proposal.clone(),
            };
let call_formatted = Self::get_formatted_call(call.into());
let call_dispatch = Box::new(call_formatted);
```

4. FINALLY!! after these steps, we can create proposal_hash & proposal_encoded!!!

   `let proposal_hash = T::Hashing::hash_of(&call_dispatch);`

   `let proposal_encoded: Vec<u8> = call_dispatch.encode();`

With these I can create a valid preimage, and the proposal is correctly enacted by Democracy pallet. HOWEVER, after spending days reading the democracy pallet tests and benchmarking, this wasn't the solution I was expecting, and I'm pretty confused. If anyone could provide some answers to the questions above...please? Question in the answer....

#### Edit1:

Forgot to add the content of the call_dispatch function, which HAS TO use Root:

```
pub fn execute_call_dispatch(origin: OriginFor<T>, account_id: AccountIdOf<T>,  proposal: Box<<T as Config>::Call>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
ensure_root(origin)?;
proposal.dispatch_bypass_filter(frame_system::RawOrigin::Signed(account_id.clone()).into()).ok();
Ok(().into())}
```

Kazu